# Commenting out a line with Ansible lineinfile module

Tags: ansible

I find it hard to believe there isn't anything that covers this use case but my search has proved fruitless.

I have a line in `/etc/fstab` to mount a drive that's no longer available:

```
//archive/Pipeline /pipeline/Archives cifs ro,credentials=/home/username/.config/cifs 0   0
```

What I want is to change it to

```
#//archive/Pipeline /pipeline/Archives cifs ro,credentials=/home/username/.config/cifs 0   0
```

I was using this

```
---
- hosts: slurm
  remote_user: root

  tasks:
    - name: Comment out pipeline archive in fstab
      lineinfile:
        dest: /etc/fstab
        regexp: '^//archive/pipeline'
        line: '#//archive/pipeline'
        state: present
      tags: update-fstab
```

expecting it to just insert the comment symbol (#), but instead it replaced the whole line and I ended up with

```
#//archive/Pipeline
```

is there a way to glob-capture the rest of the line or just insert the single comment char?

```
 regexp: '^//archive/pipeline *'
 line: '#//archive/pipeline *'
```

or

```
 regexp: '^//archive/pipeline *'
 line: '#//archive/pipeline $1'
```

I am trying to wrap my head around lineinfile and from what I"ve read it looks like insertafter is what I'm looking for, but "insert after" isn't what I want?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the [`replace`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html) module for your case:

```
---
- hosts: slurm
  remote_user: root

  tasks:
    - name: Comment out pipeline archive in fstab
      replace:
        dest: /etc/fstab
        regexp: '^//archive/pipeline'
        replace: '#//archive/pipeline'
      tags: update-fstab
```

It will replace all occurrences of the string that matches `regexp`.

`lineinfile` on the other hand, works only on one line (even if multiple matching are find in a file). It ensures a particular line is absent or present with a defined content.

Comment: `lineinfile` can be looped until changed is false, but that messes with a lot more things... `replace` is the right way...

Answer (score 32):

Use [backrefs=yes](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html):

> Used with state=present. If set, line can contain backreferences (both positional and named) that will get populated if the regexp matches.

Like this:

```
- name: Comment out pipeline archive in fstab
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/fstab
    regexp: '(?i)^(//archive/pipeline.*)'
    line: '# \1'
    backrefs: yes
    state: present
```

Also note that I use `(?i)` option for regexp, because your search expression will never match `Pipeline` with capital P in the example fstab.

Comment: Thanks Konstantin, a good answer, but I've decided to use replace.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the many reasons `lineinfile` is an antipattern. In many cases, a template is the best solution. In this case, the `mount` module was designed for this.

```
- name: Remove the pipeline archive
  mount: name="/archive/pipeline" state=absent
```

But "ah!" you say, you "want to preserve that the mount was in fstab at one time". You've done one better by using `mount`, you've preserved it **in ansible**.

Comment: I like the idea of preserving the config in ansible. However in this case wouldn't you still loose the configuration parameters (like the location of the credentials file in the example)?