# Ansible Lineinfile - expect one or another

Tags: ansible

My ansible gets som items out of an list called modules. I want to make sure that these items are in an txt file.

```
- name: copy modules to setup file
  lineinfile:
   path: /etc/path/txt
   line: "#{{ item }}"
   state: present
   regexp: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ modules }}"
  when: modules is defined and (modules | length > 0)
```

So, this should do add "#item" to the list, but the problem is, i don't want it to overwrite "item" if it is there. It should be some kind of backup that adds the item commented but only if it isn't uncommented in the file, is there some way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Commenting out a line with Ansible lineinfile module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239602/commenting-out-a-line-with-ansible-lineinfile-module)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be to test the presence of the *item* in the whole file.

```
- set_fact:
    content: "{{ lookup('file','/etc/path/txt') }}"
- name: copy modules to setup file
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/path/txt
    line: "#{{ item }}"
    state: present
  loop: "{{ modules|default([]) }}"
  when: not content|regex_search('.*' + item + '.*' | string)
```

- "*modules|default([])*" solves the missing test "modules is defined".
- The test "*modules | length > 0*" is redundant.

Comment: i used your version to create my own, instead of set_fact i use a shell cat and register it. my when is: 
when: '"{{ item }}" not in content.stdout'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u can use this task twice. And in the first with check: true and register that result to state it in the second task at the when condition.